# Which weapon or character in Bowmasters does the most damage?

Tags: bowmasters

In the [Bowmasters](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bowmasters/id1118431695?mt=8) mobile phone game, there are a variety of unloackable characters, each of which have their own custom weapon with certain perks.

[image: Bowmasters Weapons and Characters]

Is there an unlockable character or weapon which does the most damage?

Answer (score 1):

The one that does the most damage would probably be the hipster; a nearly assured two shot on anywhere on the body.

Comment: I've noticed that as well when playing against a computer player that is the Hipster but haven't seen this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Lumberjack can deal insane amounts of damage if his chainsaw hits properly.
Thor also deals a lot of damage if the actual weapon hits about 1/2. 
Maestro one time 2 shot me because I landed in his acid.
Neko deals a lot of damage if all 3 kunai's hit.
Test around with some of the characters and see which best works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's Jeremy his trash can contains multiple of other weapons and does so much damage a headshot is equivalent to 3/4 of your health.

Answer (score 0):

The lumberjack can do a LOT of damage if it hits right. The hipster somehow also does crazy damage and can one-shot the opponent. Betty, the one who throws a watermelon, is ABSOLUTELY OP. Her watermelon can also one-shot the opponent and it doesn't matter where it hits because it nearly always takes away 2/3 to 3/4 of the opponent's health.

Comment: So which one is the strongest?

Answer (score -1):

I say Y, the dj, and his grenade is super op. Terrance the lumberjack is op, his chainsaw if hit correctly can have a chain effect of head shots and other chain attacks (yes puns intended). Cyborg, the guy in the green tech suit his CD's are a little bit op.